# how can i create a camel webcocket client? Suggest some reference examples

Tags: java, websocket, apache-camel

I am trying to create a websocket client using camel.. Can we implement it using atmosphere websocket.I have referred the document in camel official site. Could you please provide some reference examples on to create a websocket client?

I also tried using ahc with the below code, and the server gets started with the below log,
but i get no response on the client side where the server is continuously sending data

````
        from("ahc-ws://localhost:8180/receive/public")
        .log(">>> Message received from WebSocket Client : ${body}")
        .transform().simple("${body}${body}");```

Starting CamelMainRunController to ensure the main thread keeps running
2020-04-09 05:40:58.619 INFO 7636 --- [ main] o.a.camel.component.ahc.ws.WsEndpoint : Reconnecting websocket: ws://localhost:8180/ws/recieve/public
2020-04-09 05:40:58.636 INFO 7636 --- [inRunController] org.apache.camel.main.BaseMainSupport : Using properties from classpath:application.properties;optional=true
2020-04-09 05:41:00.309 INFO 7636 --- [ main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext : Route: route1 started and consuming from: ahc-ws://localhost:8180/ws/recieve/public
2020-04-09 05:41:00.325 INFO 7636 --- [ main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2020-04-09 05:41:00.326 INFO 7636 --- [ main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext : Apache Camel 3.1.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 3.845 seconds
2020-04-09 05:41:00.417 INFO 7636 --- [ main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-04-09 05:41:00.429 INFO 7636 --- [ main] c.w.server.WebsocketClientApplication : Started WebsocketClientApplication in 60.888 seconds (JVM running for 66.527)
````